# Imageshack API callback URL

Tags: url, callback, imageshack

I just built a photo app for Facebook and wanted to use imageshack to host the images.

I Spent some time with their API but can't figure out how to get the callback URL. can someone please tell me how to do this?

Thanks,
Rajiv

Answer (score 0):

if u call this API url. http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php
add the xml=yes at the end. Become like this  http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php?xml=yes 
so you can get the respond return as xml format and u can get all the detail inside the xml. the example of the xml return can see it under the comment at here http://code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/wiki/ImageshackAPI